# struct as a base class - C/C++ interoperability

Tags: c++, c, class, oop, struct

I recall I saw somewhere some code which used to have a struct as a base class, and a C++ class as a derived class

```
struct Base_Struct
{

}

class Derived : Base_Struct
{
  ...
}
```

And the point is that a pointer to Base_Struct* was passed from the C++ files to some C files which then managed to use some function pointers in Base_Struct.

My question is: if I pass Base_Struct* to a C file, will the C code be able to use the Base_Struct completely? What about the derived class?

Comment: My understanding of allocation of class structures is that the base class is first, and the dirived class members are stored after the base class. This should work. But I am not a language lawyer, so don't take my word for it. An array of structures may not work since they would be larger than Base_Struct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I pass `Base_Struct*` to a C file, will the C code be able to use the `Base_Struct` completely?

If it's a standard-layout class, and the C compiler uses the same ABI for such classes as the C++ compiler, then it can access all the data members. Obviously, it couldn't access any member functions or static members, since such things don't exist in C and would have to be left out of any C-compatible definition of the structure.

> What about the derived class?

You couldn't define that class in a C program, so it couldn't do anything interesting with the pointer.

Comment: Where "standard-layout class" means [Plain Old Data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_data), i.e. something which can be compiled by a C compiler.  If it uses any C++ features (private/protected members, virtual functions, or it has a parent class/struct), it's not POD.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield: No, "standard-layout class" means "standard-layout class". POD is a special case of standard layout, with more restrictions.

Comment: The main reason (for me, at least) to extend structures from C API is to give them a default constructor which will zero out their fields, and maybe a destructor...

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Thanks for the correction.  I hadn't heard of the term "standard-layout class" before today, but apparently it's a new concept added in C++11 (I only work with C++03 these days because some of the compilers I use don't yet support C++11).

Answer (score 1):

**Maybe** it can work for the base class. But that is on very special case:

- POD struct
- same packing
- same runtime if you allocate/deallocate in C and C++
- pure C syntax
- etc...

But it will **never** directly for the derived class.

But that create so many restriction that I would provide a C level API to allocate an manipulate those pointers defined as alias on "void*" (I'm not even sure you can do such aliases this in pure C).

Something like:

```
 typedef void* BaseStructPtr;

 BaseStructPtr AllocateBase(/* constructor params */);
 BaseStructPtr AllocateDerived(/* constructor params */);

 TypeOfField1 GetField1(BaseStructPtr ptr);
 TypeOfField2 GetField2(BaseStructPtr ptr);

 /* etc... */
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not see any problem to derive from a structure declared in C:

**C/C++**

```
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

typedef struct {
    int a;
    int b;
} X;

void print(struct StructX* x) {
    printf("%d, %d\n", x->a, x->b);
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
} // extern "C"
#endif
```

**C++**

```
#include <iostream>

struct Y : StructX {
    int c;

    Y()
    : c(3)
    {
        a = 1;
        b = 2;
    }

    void print() {
        ::print(this);
        std::cout << c << std::endl;
    }
};


int main() {
    Y y;
    y.print();
}
```

Having the structure declared in C++ will complicate things.
Now the struct might (or will) have information C is not aware of and(lets say)
a memcpy could introduce undefined behavior. To avoid this you would have to
wrap the functionality of the C++ structure in C:

**C/C++**

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

typedef struct Z; // An opaque type (for X) to ensure minimum type safety.

extern int a(Z*);
extern int b(Z*);

#ifdef __cplusplus
} // extern "C"
#endif
```

**C++**

```
extern "C" {
    int a(Z* z) {
        return ((X*)z)->a;
    }
    int b(Z* z) {
        return ((X*)z)->b;
    }
} // extern "C"
```

Answer (score 1):

In your sample yes a C compiler will be able to use the Base_Struct* pointer and access members. You can use the same struct definition in C and CPP files without problems. As long as it's the Cpp who cast the struct for the C file the compiler will do the job.

```
void Give_Typed_Pointer_to_C_Function(Base_Struct* pStruct) {...}
void Give_Pointer_to_C_Function(void* pStruct) {...}
Base_Struct A;
Derived B;
Give_Typed_Pointer_to_C_Function(&A);         // OK
Give_Typed_Pointer_to_C_Function(&B);         // OK 
Give_Pointer_to_C_Function(&A);               // OK    
Give_Pointer_to_C_Function(&B);               // wrong
Give_Pointer_to_C_Function((Base_Struct*)&B); // OK
```

For this to work you have to use the same alignment and packing of struct but as you pass pointer I suppose you are same project so it should be already be the case.

You can even do more, if you keep struct in same order

```
struct S1 { int x; 
            int y;
          };
class C1 {  int x;
            int y;
            int add(int,int); 
          };
void Give_Typed_Pointer_to_C_Function(S1 *pStruct);
C1 object;
Give_Typed_Pointer_to_C_Function((S1*)&object);  // OK

// an safer alternative as you can't have to be sure that S1 and C1 match
struct C1 { int x;
            int y;
#ifdef __cplusplus
            int add(int,int); 
#endif
          };
```

If you put Cpp keyword like class/public/private and methods in struct with defines. And if you don't use inheritance it will work as well.